# regex capture everything between special characters

Tags: regex, perl

I need to capture in perl everything between { and },{ in a string. Occurrences can exists from 0 to a finite number.

I've tried to use:

```
my @tmp;
my $extract = "";                   
$extract = $1 if $json =~ /\{([^}]+)\}/g;
push @tmp, $extract;
```

Where $json is the string where I need to extract the content.

Here is an example of two items of *$json*:

> {"id":"AAAAAAAAAA","text":"AAAAAAAAAA","icon":"jstree-folder","li_attr":{"id":"AAAAAAAAAA"},"a_attr":{"href":"#","id":"AAAAAAAAAA_anchor"},"state":{"loaded":true,"opened":true,"selected":false,"disabled":false},"data":{"Taginfo":"default","Type":"","Measure":"","Scale":"default","Filter":"","Concept":"default","Uso":"default","Uso2":"default","Parciales":1},"parent":"#"},{"id":"BBBBBBBBBBBBB","text":"BBBBBBBBBBBBB","icon":"jstree-folder","li_attr":{"id":"BBBBBBBBBBBBB"},"a_attr":{"href":"AAAAAAAAAA","id":"BBBBBBBBBBBBB_anchor"},"state":{"loaded":true,"opened":false,"selected":true,"disabled":false},"data":{"Taginfo":"BBBBBBBBBBBBB","Type":"default","Measure":"default","Scale":"1000","Filter":"1000","Concept":"default","Uso":"","Uso2":"","Parciales":1},"parent":"AAAAAAAAAA"}

Using the regex above, I'm not getting the correct string. i.e: In the first occurrence has to be:

> {"id":"AAAAAAAAAA","text":"AAAAAAAAAA","icon":"jstree-folder","li_attr":{"id":"AAAAAAAAAA"},"a_attr":{"href":"#","id":"AAAAAAAAAA_anchor"},"state":{"loaded":true,"opened":true,"selected":false,"disabled":false},"data":{"Taginfo":"default","Type":"","Measure":"","Scale":"default","Filter":"","Concept":"default","Uso":"default","Uso2":"default","Parciales":1},"parent":"#"}

So, I need to capture until the next:

```
},{
```

My question is how to ignore end the capture group with },{ instead of just with }?

Thanks.

Comment: You should really not invent your own JSON parser. There are enough of those on CPAN already. ;-) it seems though as if the problem your are trying to solve is that there are multiple json objects in one variable. It looks as if they are delimited by line breaks. Why not just split on `/\}\n/`?

Comment: This is an XY problem - please give some example data and what you're trying to extract. It is _almost certainly_ much easier and cleaner to use a JSON parser to accomplish this.

Comment: I'd done that when I created the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to use a recursive matching pattern to match closing `{ .. }` like this:

```
\{(?:[^{}]+|(?0))*}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eHeVnb/2)

Here `(?0)` recurses the entire pattern.

Though if you are parsing a valid JSON string then it is better to use JSON parser.